# Intellisense Javascript - Visual Studio 2017

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, intellisense

I have installed Visual Studio 2017 but there isn't a javascript IntelliSense. Do I have to install "Javascript snippet pack"?

I installed "web application" mode.
I notice that into "Tools" - "Option" - "TextEditor" - "Javascript/Typescript" is not presenT "Reference".

Thanks all
Morris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this problem by uninstalling and reinstalling Visual Studio.
Before reinstalling it, I deleted all visual studio folders of latest versions in "C:/User/Documents".

Comment: Hi Morris, glad to hear that your issue is solved, you can mark your reply as answer, it will helpful for other community members who meet the same or similar issue to easier search this useful information.

Comment: I added it how confirmed response :)

Answer (score 1):

I found similar problem when using Visual Studio 2017. The IntelliSense of **JavaScript/TypeScript** didn't not functional property, recently.

**Problem found:**
There was missing **JavaScript/TypeScript** in Text Editor after checking in menu Tools > Options > Text Editor.

**Solutions:**
Then I fixed it by using repair option for Visual Studio and it back to functional property.